# Android toolbar save state when visible/gone

Tags: java, android

I'm making a calculator (those bits are not shown in the code below) and I have a toolbar at the bottom of the application, and I can toggle its visibility from a menu. This is my current MainActivity class:

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity implements OnClickListener {

        public Toolbar toolbar_btm;

        @Override
        public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        toolbar_btm = findViewById(R.id.toolbar_bottom);
        }

        @Override
        protected void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle outState) {
            super.onSaveInstanceState(outState);

            //Toolbar toolbar_btm = findViewById(R.id.toolbar_bottom);
            outState.putInt("TOOLBAR_VISIBLE", toolbar_btm.getVisibility());
        }

        @Override
        protected void onRestoreInstanceState(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onRestoreInstanceState(savedInstanceState);

            //Toolbar toolbar_btm = findViewById(R.id.toolbar_bottom);
            toolbar_btm.setVisibility(savedInstanceState.getInt("TOOLBAR_VISIBLE"));
        }

        //Toggles the toolbar to show/hide
        @Override
        public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {

            switch (item.getItemId()) {
                case R.id.toolbar_toggle:
                    Toolbar toolbar_btmtog = findViewById(R.id.toolbar_bottom);
                    if (toolbar_btmtog.getVisibility() == View.GONE)
                        toolbar_btmtog.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                    else if (toolbar_btmtog.getVisibility() == View.VISIBLE)
                        toolbar_btmtog.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                    return true;
                default:
                    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
            }
        }
}
```

However, I cannot seem to keep this visible/gone state in memory. I've tried using onSaveInstanceState and onRestoreInstanceState, but when I run my code, it throws the following exception:

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity
ComponentInfo{com.example.calculator/com.example.calculator.MainActivity}: 
java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void 
android.widget.Toolbar.setVisibility(int)' on a null object reference
```

I simply cannot figure out what the issue is. I'm using `putInt` and `getInt` and I'm declaring the toolbar with the right name. So, why am I getting a null object reference?

Comment: create custom toolbar for your activity

Comment: what line is it crashing on

Comment: It's right after the restore function,  
`toolbar_btm.setVisibility(savedInstanceState.getInt("TOOLBAR_VISIBLE"));`

Comment: Have you tried declaring global `Toolbar` variable and initialize it in `onResume()` ? In any case you should initialize it only once per lifecycle.

Comment: Create your toolbar only once in onCreate please

Comment: I'm not sure how to do that though. I have `Toolbar toolbar_btm = (Toolbar)findViewById(toolbar_bottom);` in onCreate, but I get "Cannot resolve symbol" in the onSave/onRestore functions. I tried to change the functions to public instead of protected, but that didn't work.

Comment: You declare a variable by writing `Toolbar toolbar;`
You assign (initialize) variable by writing `toolbar = ....`
You should declare it in class level. Not in function.

Comment: I declaed it in my MainActivity class:

    `public class MainActivity extends Activity implements OnClickListener {

    Toolbar toolbar_btm = (Toolbar)findViewById(toolbar_bottom);
    ...
    }`

It wanted me to import it as a static import with: `import static com.example.calculator.R.id.toolbar_bottom;`

And now the application crashes at startup.

Comment: When you use `Toolbar toolbar_btm = findViewById(R.id.toolbar_bottom);` you're not using that global object, you're creating another one with the same name.
On the other hand you cannot call findViewById on class level, since View hasn't been initialized.

Comment: Okay, I created `Toolbar toolbar_bottom;` in the main class, and it got me a little further. Now it tells me that "Attempt to invoke virtual method 'int android.widget.Toolbar.getVisibility()' on a null object reference". So it went from setVisitility to getVisibility.

Comment: If you want further help, please update your question with the new code, and try to include whole Activity with irrelevant part replaced by ex. "..."

Comment: @Gotiasits, I updated the whole code now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. You have two varaibles named `toolbar_btm`. One is global and unassigned, and another is in  `onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item)`. That local variable "overwrites" local variable (in function)
2. You should declare Toolbar as global, and then assign its value in `OnCreate()` or, if that doesn't work, in overridden function `OnResume()`. You assign value by **not** using `Toolbar` keyword for a second time, so like this.

   `toolbar_btm = findViewById(R.id.toolbar_bottom);`

**UPDATE:**

3. You could also drop Toolbar altogether and use ActionBar instead. This snippet will toggle action bar visibility in Activity (not Fragment):

```
        ActionBar actionBar = getActionBar();

        if(actionBar.isShowing())
            actionBar.hide();
        else
            actionBar.show();

        this.invalidateOptionsMenu();
```

Comment: Tried with `onResume()`, but gave same error as before. I also added `toolbar_btm = findViewById(R.id.toolbar_bottom);` to `onCreate`, but no luck there either. I also declared the toolbar as global and used a local variable for the menu, but same result. Right now, the exception is `setVisibility(int)`.

Answer (score 1):

You are not assigning your Toolbar variable. After menu option was selected you are using local one. Put this code in `onCreate()` :

```
toolbar_btm = findViewById(R.id.toolbar_bottom);
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for that! I added that to `onCreate` (see updated code above), but it still throws the exception: `Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.widget.Toolbar.setVisibility(int)' on a null object reference` when I turn the device in landscape mode.

Comment: try adding `if(savedInstanceState != null) toolbar_btm.setVisibility(savedInstanceState.getInt("TOOLBAR_VISIBLE")); ` in `onCreate()`. And remove setting visibility from `onRestoreInstanceState`

Comment: I did exactly that, but still the same error: `Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.widget.Toolbar.setVisibility(int)' on a null object reference` and it was pointing on the line where `if(savedInstanceState != null)...` is.

Comment: did you put in before or after `toolbar_btm = findViewById(R.id.toolbar_bottom);`?